# R's lm() function removes factor levels (aside from intercept estimator) without reporting error or warning

Tags: r, lm, anova

I am attempting to fit a linear model, using forward stepwise ANOVA and AIC selection criterion, to a fairly large unbalanced data set, with interaction terms. There are 13,072 observations. Here's how it's set up:

**Response variable** `dayseclosion` **is continuous numeric**

**Explanatory variables are all categorical:** `host` (4 levels), `site` (25 levels), `year` (5 levels), `monoverwinter` (4 levels).

```
> glimpse(dat)
Observations: 13,072
Variables: 5
$ site          <chr> "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "14", "14", "15", "15",…
$ year          <chr> "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2017", "2017…
$ host          <chr> "3", "3", "4", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"…
$ monoverwinter <chr> "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5"…
$ dayseclose    <dbl> 11, 12, 17, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 2…

m0 –> lm(dayseclose ~ 1, data = dat)
model.aic.forward –> step(m0, direction = "forward", trace = 1, scope = ~ host * monoverwinter * site * year)
```

Now, when I say the data are unbalanced, I mean that not all 4`host` were collected at all 25`site` in all 5`year`, and there was unequal representation of 4`monoverwinter` experimental treatments among other factor levels. However, there are still large numbers of observations (=hundreds) within each factor level.

Everything seems to run fine—**no Warnings and no Errors**. The following model is selected:

```
## Step:  AIC=61561.31
## dayseclose ~ host + site + monoverwinter + year + host:site + 
##     host:monoverwinter + site:monoverwinter + site:year
## 
##                           Df Sum of Sq     RSS   AIC
## <none>                                 1433157 61561
## + host:year                1     8.059 1433149 61563
## + host:monoverwinter:site  3   242.885 1432914 61565
```

**The problem** is when I inspect the `summary()` and `anova()` tables, which reveal that one of the factor levels associated with `year` is being mysteriously removed (`year2020`). NOTE, this is not the level being used to estimate the intercept (that is `year2016`). There are 3,581 observations for that year, yet in the `summary(model.aic.forward)` table, the coefficients are (only partial shown):

```
## year2017                           6.36787    2.44775   2.602 0.009292 ** 
## year2018                          -0.13757    1.85568  -0.074 0.940906    
## year2019                         -10.56667    3.45693  -3.057 0.002243 ** 
## year2020                                NA         NA      NA       NA
```

Also not shown here, but all interactions with `year2020` specifically, also appear NA.

Oddly, based on the F-stat degrees of freedom it appears all observations, including `year2020` are being used to fit the model (79 + 12992 = 13071):

```
## Residual standard error: 10.5 on 12992 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.3105, Adjusted R-squared:  0.3063 
## F-statistic: 74.06 on 79 and 12992 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Finally (I know this is long), the `df` for `year` in the anova table is 3 but should be 4, given five factor levels in the data:

```
d =anova(model.aic.forward)
as_tibble(d, rownames = "Predictors")

## # A tibble: 9 x 6
##   Predictors             Df `Sum Sq` `Mean Sq` `F value`  `Pr(>F)`
##   <chr>              <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1 host                   3  497707.   165902.   1504.    0.      
## 2 site                  24   43276.     1803.     16.3   3.77e-67
## 3 monoverwinter          3   34395.    11465.    104.    1.73e-66
## 4 year                   3    2422.      807.      7.32  6.71e- 5
## 5 host:site             16   43445.     2715.     24.6   1.08e-72
## 6 host:monoverwinter     3    7319.     2440.     22.1   2.80e-14
## 7 site:monoverwinter    12    9229.      769.      6.97  9.13e-13
## 8 site:year             15    7646.      510.      4.62  6.30e- 9
## 9 Residuals          12992 1433157.      110.     NA    NA
```

Am I interpreting this wrong? What is happening to `year2020`? Could the unbalanced nature of the data be causing this? I can't imagine how to provide a minimal reproducible example, since it is likely the amount and complexity of the data that is causing the issue?

Thank you for reading and potentially help solve this puzzle.

Comment: In order to have a full rank design matrix and since your model has an intercept, one of the factor levels needs to be removed as a result of dummy encoding the categorical variables. If you remove the intercept, you will recover the "missing" factor level.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thank you for your response. I considered what you've proposed, however, there is yet a different 'year' that is being used to estimate intercept (year2016). In addition, the df in the anova table also indicates that two years have been removed. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I think you're right in your guess that this has to do with the unbalanced design. Can you check for which `host`s and `site`s do you have `year = 2020` measurements? I think we will need access to the specific data to understand what is going on. An `NA` coefficient generally means that the parameter cannot be estimated.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I edited post to more clearly state about the intercept issue. As for posting data, I need to check whether and how I can do this. More soon...Thank you for your interest!

Comment: `lm` drops columns from the design matrix in order to get a non-singular design matrix, try running `lm` with `singular.ok=FALSE` and also inspect the model matrix `mm <- model.matrix(dayseclose ~ host * monoverwinter * site * year, data = dat)` or try running `lm` directly with the model matrix `lm(dat$dayseclose ~ mm, singular.ok=FALSE)`

Comment: Sigh, I have accepted the fact that I cannot use lm() given the data structure. It seems I would need at least one observation for each level (i.e., all hosts at all sites for all years with all monoverwinter treatments) Each response indicates this (thank you all). So, perhaps a linear mixed model or Bayesian model. Time to crack some books.

Comment: @Monte I don't think mixed/Bayesian models will help if you have no observations for some groups, as the issue with identifiability remains. I'd be curious to hear a more in-depth answer though. I recommend asking a new question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/); then perhaps drop a link here so that interested people can follow the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your missingness is probably causing your results.

Consider the following reproducible example.

```
x1 <- sample(1:5, 1000, replace=T)  
x2 <- sample(1:3, 1000, replace=T)
y <- 2*x1 + 3*x2 + rnorm(1000)
#no missings (everything works fine)
lm(y~as.factor(x1) + as.factor(x2))
lm(y~ -1 + as.factor(x1) + as.factor(x2)) # no intercept
#with missings
x1[x2==2]<-NA #create specific missingness
table(x1,useNA = "always")
table(x2,useNA = "always")
table(x1,x2,useNA = "always") #you see the missing pattern
lm(y~ as.factor(x1) + as.factor(x2))
lm(y~ -1 + as.factor(x1) + as.factor(x2))
```

If you run the code, you will see that for factor x2 two categories are omitted. The first is the ref.cat. the second `(x2)2` because of the missings.